# Find an item inside a List<T> by providing a sample object instance

Tags: c#, list, icollection, iequatable

Why is there a `List<T>.Contains(T)` method but no `List<T>.Find(T)` method? Only the `Find`s that support predicates are supported. If we have an existing instance of T populated with a property value for its ID (but missing other properties) why can't we search by providing this object instance to the search in `List`, especially when we have implemented custom `IEquatable<T>` for `T` and would like to use what's there. But as it is, we can't, we have to repeat everything that we did in `IEquatable` implementation in our `Find(predicate)` call.

Comment: What is the use of a `Find(T)` method, when you already have that instance? That would be equivalent to the `Contains(T)` method, because the only thing the `Find(T)` will tell you is whether that list contains that instance.

Comment: I imagine because he's trying to get a reference to the object in the list... just because he has an object that "equals" the other, especially considering that he implemented IEquatable and it's not just a reference comparison, that doesn't mean he's got a reference to the object he wants.

Comment: exactly as antisanity puts it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can call the `IEquatable<T>` member(s) in your `Predicate<T>`. Then you won't be repeating yourself.

```
MyClass a = new MyClass(); //sample for finding; IEquatable<MyClass>
List<MyClass> list = GetInstances();

MyClass found = list.Find( mc => mc.Equals(a) );
```

Answer (score 1):

how about this

```
list.Any(i => i.ID == searchObj.ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

I think I understood your question now. You can use the [`List<T>.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx) method for this purpose:

```
int index = myList.IndexOf(mySample);

if(index != -1)
{
   var item = myList[index];
   // Do something with item.
}
```

But this would be quite strange, because clearly, your equality definition isn't quite the whole picture - it's a bit of an abuse of equality, IMO.

Comment: MSDN: This method determines equality using the default equality comparer EqualityComparer<T>.Default for T. This method performs a linear search; therefore, this method is an O(n) operation

Comment: My equality definition is just fine, it just says that two properties define the equality not just one.